# how do i save a concatenate DataFrame name as the original .csv file name in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a folder which contain files like: `ANGOSTURA_U1_20220901.csv` ,`ANGOSTURA_U1_20220902.csv`, `ANGOSTURA_U1_20220903.csv`

I want to read all files and concatenated in one csv and print this cocatenated df as  `ANGOSTURA_U1_202209_month.csv`

Take into consideration that these files can be called `Colbun_U1_20220801.csv`, `Colbun_U1_20220802.csv`, `Colbun_U1_20220803.csv` , but I want the file name output always be the first name and the date. In this case it would be : `Colbun_U1_202208_month.csv` if the files are `ANGOSTURA_U1_XXXX01.csv` output file name: `ANGOSTURA_U1_XXXX_month.csv`, if the files are `Colbun_U2_XXXX01.csv` output file name: `Colbun_U2_XXXX_month.csv` but it always be in the folder either Colbun or Angostura not both

This is my code: (i try  `os.listdir` and  `glob.glob`)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import csv
all_files = glob.glob("C:/Users/ep_irojaso/Desktop/PROGRAMA DESEMPEÑO/saturnmensual/*.csv")
file_list = []
  for f in (all_files):   
   data = pd.read_csv(f,usecols=["t","f"])

   file_list.append(data)
df=pd.concat(file_list,ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv(f'C:/Users/ep_irojaso/Desktop/PROGRAMA DESEMPEÑO/Saturn2mensual/{os.path.basename(f).split(".")[0]}_mensual.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
from itertools import groupby
from pathlib import Path

def key(file_path): return file_path.stem[:-2]

base = Path("C:/Users/ep_irojaso/Desktop/PROGRAMA DESEMPEÑO/saturnmensual/")
all_files = sorted(base.glob("*.csv"))
for key, files in groupby(all_files, key=key):
    pd.concat(
        [pd.read_csv(file, usecols=["t", "f"]) for file in files]
    ).to_csv(base / f"{key}_month.csv", index=False)
```

- Use `pathlib` from the standard library instead of `os`: set the `base` path to the folder that contains the CSV-files.
- `glob` all CSV-files in it and sort them into a list `all_files`.
- Now group the files into monthly buckets with `groupby` from the standard library module `itertools`. The grouping key is the file name without the extension and the last to  characters (the days according to your specification).
- Then concat all the dataframes from one month and write the new dataframe to a new CSV-file.